# How to get Base64 Output?

Tags: react-native, ffmpeg

I am using react-native-ffmpeg library to get frames from a video file with this code;

```
RNFFmpeg.execute(`-ss 00:00:03 -to 00:00:04 -i input.mp4 -vf fps=1 ${RNFS.PicturesDirectoryPath}/out%05d.png`)
```

This works as expected, saves the frames to given file but i need to render the frames before saving to the file system. So i thought i can use base64 encoding to get the image without saving. But i couldn't find any solution for this. Do you guys have any idea about solving this problem. If there is another solution rather than base64 encoding for getting the images before saving to filesystem i will happy to see that too. Thanks!

Edit:
There is a function called av_base64_decode in the documentation but i don't know how to use with my code.

Edit: I read about piping the output but i can't find anything base64 related.